# Finite Difference Method Heat Equation problems at boundary between two materials

Tags: thermodynamics, computational-physics

For a project I am assigned to solve the heat equation in a 2D environment in Python. To do this, I am using the Crank-Nicolson ADI scheme and so far things have been going smooth. I would also like to add that this is the first time that I have done numerical computing like this and I don't have a lot of experience with PDE's and finite difference methods.

However, problems start when I try to add a second material with a different thermal diffusivity. At the boundaries of the 2 materials, the temperature keeps rising and rising exponentially, but only at the boundaries (as if they are a heat source). Any other place in the domain functions fine and does not show this behaviour at all.
Why does this happen and how can I stop it? Do I need to impose new boundary conditions on these boundaries, or can I just 'force' my way through this by calculating the temperature on the boundary and treating the two materials as independent domains?

Comment: What is your finite difference equation for matching the heat fluxes at the boundary?

Comment: Currently the whole domain has fixed temperature boundary conditions at the edges of the (square) domain. I haven't implemented boundary conditions between the two materials because I thought the program could just calculate the temperature values, only with a different thermal diffusivity. I know there is such a thing as thermal resistance, but I wanted to add that later. I just cant understand why the boundaries between the materials get so 'hot'.

Comment: Like I said, what is the heat flux matching boundary condition between the two materials?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107761/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13996/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137705/25301, etc

Comment: Do you use a single domain, with a space-varying diffusivity, or two connected domains which share a common boundary? The answer would be quite different…

Comment: I use a single domain with space-varying diffusivity; the lower part of the domain has a high diffusivity and the upper part has a low diffusivity for example.  My tridiagonal matrix with the diffusivity coëfficients reflects this.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the temperature value peaks at the position *inside the grid* where the diffusivity happens to change? Then to understand you should ask yourself the following questions : 1) is this temperature increase really exponential in time? 2) if this is the case, what is the characteristic time of that exponential? 2a) is it tied to the grid/time step?  Then it's probably a numerical stability problem, and you should study the stability of your numerical scheme with space varying diffusivity 2b) is it tied to the diffusivity value(s)?

Comment: From a practical point of view, varying slowly (over a few grid points) the diffusivity (say, using sin instead of a step function) may help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about debugging code and not about a physics concept.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it got 'hot' is the interface between the two parts is not properly set. you cannot set a fixed temperature boundary condition on both parts. This "temperature" is calculated but not given. If you set a "guessed" temperature, the local temperature gradient will be unphysical. On one part, it will be a heat source or sink.